# Rsync performance - syncing a single large file vs syncing multiple small files

Tags: unix, rsync, bigdata, file-copying

I am using rsync to sync many small files (each 4.5 MB). I am using a bwlimit of 18000. I will be executing the bulk rsync command such that,

```
rsync -v dest_host:file1 dest_host:file2 dest_host:file3 dest_host:file4 dest_host:file5 ... src_dir.
```

But what I observed is that with the above bandwidth, I am not able to sync more than 4 files per minute. Is this expected? I am wondering if I have synced a single large file of 18 MB, could it be faster?

And for my above use case, are there any utility?

Comment: This link may be helpful to you: http://serverfault.com/questions/375720/speed-up-rsync-by-running-multiple-instances-at-once

Apparently my answer was too short and got converted to a comment. The full details are there at that URL anyway.

Comment: My problem is that I need to transfer files one by one in the order they are created. I can control the size of the files but I strictly want to transfer the files in the order in which they are created. One thing I want to understand is that I ve a bandwidth of 20Mbps but I can't sync more than 3 4.5 MB files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question.

Syncing multiple small files have overhead like file creation, opening, closing both at source and at destination.

And this will be significant when we transfer 100 files of size 5 MB and one file of size 500M MB.

So, the verdict, yes syncing a single large file is beneficial.